# Abstract class : invalid abstract return type for member function ‘virtual...’

Tags: c++, virtual, abstract-class

In my program I have such class hierarchy:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

class aa;
class bb;

class root
{
public:
    virtual ~root() {}
    virtual root add(const aa& a) const=0;
    virtual root add(const bb& a) const=0;
};

class aa: public root
{
public:
    aa() { }
    aa(const aa& a) { }

    virtual root add(const aa& a) const
    { return root(new aa()); }
    virtual root add(const bb& a) const
    { return root(new bb()); }
};

class bb: public root
{
public:
    bb() { }
    bb(const bb& b) {}

    virtual root add(const aa& a) const
    { return root(new bb()); }
    virtual root add(const bb& a) const
    { return root(new bb()); }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
}
```

but Im still getting errors in compilation process. I cant change my class hierarchy but it is possible to make something I want here?

**EDITED CLASS:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

class root
{
public:
    virtual ~root() {}
    virtual root add(const root& a) const=0;
    virtual root add(const root& b) const=0;
};

class aa: public root
{
public:
    aa() { }
    aa(const aa& a) { }

    virtual root add(const root& a) const
    { return root(new aa()); }
    virtual root add(const root& b) const
    { return root(new bb()); }
};

class bb: public root
{
public:
    bb() { }
    bb(const bb& b) {}

    virtual root add(const root& a) const
    { return root(new bb()); }
    virtual root add(const root& b) const
    { return root(new bb()); }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
}
```

Errors for edited class:

```
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp|11|error: ‘virtual root root::add(const root&) const’ cannot be overloaded|
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp|10|error: with ‘virtual root root::add(const root&) const’|
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp|10|error: invalid abstract return type for member function ‘virtual root root::add(const root&) const’|
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp|6|note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘root’:|
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp|10|note:     virtual root root::add(const root&) const|
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp|11|error: invalid abstract return type for member function ‘virtual root root::add(const root&) const’|
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp|6|note:   since type ‘root’ has pure virtual functions|
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp|20|error: invalid abstract return type for member function ‘virtual root aa::add(const root&) const’|
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp|6|note:   since type ‘root’ has pure virtual functions|
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp|22|error: invalid abstract return type for member function ‘virtual root aa::add(const root&) const’|
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp|6|note:   since type ‘root’ has pure virtual functions|
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp|22|error: ‘virtual root aa::add(const root&) const’ cannot be overloaded|
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp|20|error: with ‘virtual root aa::add(const root&) const’|
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp||In member function ‘virtual root aa::add(const root&) const’:|
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp|20|error: invalid abstract return type for member function ‘virtual root aa::add(const root&) const’|
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp|6|note:   since type ‘root’ has pure virtual functions|
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp|21|error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘root’|
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp|6|note:   since type ‘root’ has pure virtual functions|
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp||In member function ‘virtual root aa::add(const root&) const’:|
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp|22|error: invalid abstract return type for member function ‘virtual root aa::add(const root&) const’|
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp|6|note:   since type ‘root’ has pure virtual functions|
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp|23|error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘root’|
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp|6|note:   since type ‘root’ has pure virtual functions|
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp|23|error: expected primary-expression before ‘(’ token|
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp|23|error: expected type-specifier before ‘bb’|
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp|23|error: expected ‘)’ before ‘bb’|
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp|32|error: invalid abstract return type for member function ‘virtual root bb::add(const root&) const’|
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp|6|note:   since type ‘root’ has pure virtual functions|
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp|34|error: invalid abstract return type for member function ‘virtual root bb::add(const root&) const’|
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp|6|note:   since type ‘root’ has pure virtual functions|
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp|34|error: ‘virtual root bb::add(const root&) const’ cannot be overloaded|
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp|32|error: with ‘virtual root bb::add(const root&) const’|
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp||In member function ‘virtual root bb::add(const root&) const’:|
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp|32|error: invalid abstract return type for member function ‘virtual root bb::add(const root&) const’|
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp|6|note:   since type ‘root’ has pure virtual functions|
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp|33|error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘root’|
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp|6|note:   since type ‘root’ has pure virtual functions|
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp||In member function ‘virtual root bb::add(const root&) const’:|
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp|34|error: invalid abstract return type for member function ‘virtual root bb::add(const root&) const’|
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp|6|note:   since type ‘root’ has pure virtual functions|
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp|35|error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘root’|
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp|6|note:   since type ‘root’ has pure virtual functions|
||=== Build finished: 38 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

Comment: Your design is a bit messed up. Your base class needs to know about the derived types, which isn't good. You should consider using a single member function `virtual root add(const root& a) const=0;`

Comment: @juanchopanza: Ok changed it but still have errors. Take a look at my edited question.

Comment: That issue is expertly dealt with in KerrekBS's answer. Another alternative would be to return a reference, but then you have to be sure that there is always something to refer to.

Comment: @juanchopanza that check that you mentioned applies for a pointer also right?

Comment: @Koushik no, because you can return a null pointer, which can be checked on the caller side.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You cannot return a `root` by value, since `root` is abstract and thus there can never exist any values of type `root`.

You might want to return a pointer:

```
#include <memory>

std::unique_ptr<root> do_you_feel_lucky(aa const & x, bb const & y)
{
    if (rand() % 2 == 0)
        return { new aa(x) };
    else
        return { new bb(y) };
}
```

What you have feels a lot like a "clone" or "virtual copy" function, though:

```
struct Base
{
    virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> clone() const = 0;
};

struct Derived : Base
{
    virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> clone() const
    {
        return { new Derived(*this); }
    }
};
```

Since you asked about references, here's another thing you could do, though it seems a bit pointless: Pick a reference to one among several derived objects and return a base reference.

```
root & pick_one_from_two(aa & x, bb & y)
{
    return rand() % 2 == 0 ? x : y;
}
```

Comment: +1. but is it because it is not able to construct an object of the abstract class? can we return by reference?

Comment: @Koushik: Reference to *what*? Yes, in my example you might be tempted to return just `x` or `y` as a `root const &`, but you'd encounter lifetime issues. With non-constant references that would be better, but not generally very useful (after all, you *want* to create new objects). I'll make some edits.

Comment: @Koushik: `root` is a class. I mean "reference to which *object*?".