# Cannot compile function that returns object of type MPI::Comm

Tags: c++, mpi, communicator

To run my software with MPI, I need to create a simple method that will return `MPI::COMM_WORLD`.

So in my class, we have:

```
#include <mpi.h>
class Parallel{      
    public:

        MPI::Comm getCommunicator(){
            return MPI::COMM_WORLD;
        }
    protected:

    int iproc;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    Parallel* parallel;
    MPI::Init(argc, argv);
    int my_rank;
    my_rank = parallel->getCommunicator().Get_rank();
    MPI::Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

How should I implement the `getCommunicator()` method in order it returns `MPI::COMM_WORLD`?  When I try to compile the above, I get the following error:

```
invalid abstract return type for member function 'MPI::Comm Parallel ::getCommunicator()
```

Comment: *The C++ bindings were deprecated as of MPI-2.2 (2009). The C++ bindings are removed in MPI-3.0. (2012)*. In any case I have no Idea what you are actually asking. What are you trying to do and where exactly is your problem?

Comment: Basically, I am working with HDF5 APIs to write in parallel data in a file.

Comment: In my code, I have to use including a function provided by HDF5 API:

Comment: This function is : H5Pset_fapl_mpio(plist_id,MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_INFO_NULL);   In the software in which I write code, I cannot directly called MPI_COMM_WORLD, because mpi functions are encapsulated.

Comment: So, I want to write a method in a class that returns a communicator, in particular MPI_Comm_WORLD. So, I have written above a simple code to test if my method works: in final, I have errors messages when I compile the code

Comment: Why would a piece of code know the `MPI:Comm` type, but not have access to `MPI::COMM_WORLD`. How could you possibly expect any help here without posting the error messages you get.... on an interface that was removed years ago.

Comment: In the code above, the compiler displays a error message about the type of the getCommunicator() method: "invalid abstract return type for member function 'MPI::Comm Parallel ::getCommunicator()', my goal is to return the communicator group  that contains all initial process

Answer (score 2):

Zulan is right, the C++ bindings are deleted from MPI 3, so new code really shouldn't be written using them.

The reason they've been removed is that they weren't particularly well thought out or maintained, and they're definitely not very idiomatic, so there are lots of strange cases you run into if you use them. [Boost::MPI](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0_b1/doc/html/mpi.html) is much better, but unfortunately only covers MPI 1.

If for the purposes of maintaining existing code you have to have this, the issue is as is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16457603/abstract-class-invalid-abstract-return-type-for-member-function-virtual) - at least in OpenMPI, MPI::Comm is defined as a pure virtual class, so you can't return an object of that type since there's no way of creating one; you can only return a subtype.  (I assume it was done this way so you could have intra- and inter-communicators being subtypes).

A classic way of dealing with this situation is to return a reference to the object, rather than the object itself, and let the compiler deal with the upcasting:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>

class Parallel{      
    public:
        MPI::Comm &getCommunicator(){
            return MPI::COMM_WORLD;
        }
    protected:
        int iproc;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    Parallel* parallel;
    MPI::Init(argc, argv);
    int my_rank, size;

    my_rank = parallel->getCommunicator().Get_rank();
    size = parallel->getCommunicator().Get_size();
    std::cout << my_rank << "/" << size << std::endl;
    MPI::Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Gives

```
$ mpic++ -o foo foo.cpp
$ mpiexec -np 4 ./foo
1/4
2/4
3/4
0/4
```